# Insert image into table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, playframework-2.0

I am working on a Webapplication which uses the Play Framework technology. In one of my scala.html views, I use this to simply show an image:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/image/1003.png")" width="30" height="30">
```

And it works just fine.

Now on a different site I want to build a table. The table how it is now and display it's data, works fine. So now in the first colum, I would like to put an image in every row. And this is how I thought it should work:

```
$(function () {
            $('#table').append("<thead><tr><th><a>CImage</a></th><th><a>C0</a></th><th><a>C1</a></th><th><a>C2</a></th><th><a>C3</a></th><tr></thead><tbody>");
            for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.obj.length;i++){
                $('#table').append("<tr><td><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/image/1003.png")" width="30" height="30"></td><td>"+jsonObj.obj[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.somedata[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><tr>");
            }
            $('#table').append("</tbody>");

            $("#table").tablesorter();
          }
```

But if I do that, the table doesn't show up at all. And I don't know why. The source of the image is correct. It surely cant be just because it's in an javascript function, since the other HTML-tags work fine as long as I don't try to add an image. I am very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents. In this line:

```
$('#table').append("<tr><td><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/image/1003.png")" width="30" height="30"></td><td>"+jsonObj.obj[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.somedata[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><tr>");
```

Try escaping the src, width and height `"`s, and use `'` instead of `"` for the path in the call to `@routes.Assets.at`. So, your call to `append()` should look like this:

```
$('#table').append("<tr><td><img src=\"@routes.Assets.at('images/image/1003.png')\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\"></td><td>"+jsonObj.obj[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.somedata[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><td>"+ jsonObj.someData[i]+"</td><tr>");
```

And once the code is injected, the HTML markup should look like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="@routes.Assets.at('images/image/1003.png')" width="30" height="30">
  </td><td>
    {{jsonObj.obj[i]}}
  </td><td>
    {{jsonObj.somedata[i]}}
  </td><td>
    {{jsonObj.someData[i]}}
  </td><td>
    {{jsonObj.someData[i]}}
  </td>
<tr>
```

This should be rendered by your browser as usual, *unless* inside those `obj` and `somedata` values there are hidden HTML tags or some other characters like `<` and `>`. That could mess things up, so try to check and scape those too if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do this, I get an compilation error that I have an unclosed character literal after .png. And no, neither in obj or in somedata are hidden HTML Tags. Only strings and numbers. An idea what to do now?